# Random choice with negative weights

Tags: python, random

In my python program, I have three variables `a`, `b` and `c`. They are all floats, and may be positive or negative with no upper and lower bounds.

How would I go about devising a function that takes these variables as weights and randomly chooses a corresponding action (`A`, `B` & `C`)?

**Example**:

```
a = 10
b = -2
c = 7
```

The function should perform `A` most of the time, `C` some times, and `B` the least often.

The 'weighted random functions' I found on this site do not deal with negative weights.

Comment: what *is* a negative weight? it makes no sense (in this context).

Comment: -2 is a negative weight

Comment: @VincentBeltman: no, that's an *example*.

Comment: Why do you need negative weights?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath 10, -2 and 7 are examples of weights. Since -2 is negative its a negative weight ;)

Comment: @VincentBeltman: will you please stop posting idiotic comments?

Comment: Its a gene simulation program with payoffs alloted for activities. If an animal does extremely badly, it gets a negative weight and is less likely to produce an offspring ov its own types. I have made many assumptions with respect to the actual simulation which may or may not be accurate, but the negative weight problem cannot be avoided

Comment: *"the negative weight problem cannot be avoided"* - expect by doing something sensible like normalising all weights to between 0 (no chance of reproduction) and 1 (certain reproduction).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes, that would be great, but you probably don't want to use either 0 or 1, so it's still pretty vague. I guess there's *no* right way...

Comment: Correct. But is it mathematically impossible to compute a random choice based on negative weights?

Comment: the problem is how to *properly interpret* them. until that is resolved, you cannot do math. maybe try a modified version of what @jonrsharpe suggested, and normalise weight to between 0.2 and 0.8. as you can see, it's an arbitrary interpretation, but at least you can do the math... a more proper interpretation needs the understanding of how those weights are created, and what's their exact meaning (e.g.: "less likely" is pretty vague).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select random item with weight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259989/select-random-item-with-weight)

Comment: If by weight you mean relative probability then how can it be negative?

Comment: @Karoly supposing the weights were all positive, it would be a simple matter ov ratio and proportions. I would like to achieve the same using negative weights as well.

Comment: @Andrew no, the other question says negative weights can be ignored

Comment: The simplest solution seems to be to work the weights into [0,1] range...I shall try that

Comment: based on @dataman 's idea, I would first figure out the distribution of the weights. then at least you can *try* to treat it like you're doing math and not wild guessing.

Comment: Unless you really mean [negative probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability), your weights should all be positive. Or do is this somehow related to e.g. electrical charge, which of course can be negative?

Comment: Negative numbers don't really make much sense, but if you want to add `-10` for example, you could instead consider adding a weight of `1/10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
weights = [10, -2, 7]
offset = min(weights)
positiveweights = [z - offset + 1 for z in weights]
```

Now you can use any weighted random function that requires positive weights.

Comment: Do the weights behave correctly though? An offset of `5` vs `0` could change the result to `[5, 6]` vs `[0, 1]` which from what I know behaves differently

Answer (score 1):

Well, an easy way is to assume that the values of your variables come from a normal distribution with the `mean` equal to largest value(*) and an arbitrary standard deviation (e.g. `sd=1`).

Then, what you need to do is simply to find the probability of seeing a specific value such as `-2` which can be solved by probability distribution function (**pdf**). Then you can use the probabilities as weights.

The good thing about this method is that you can have also negative values.

**Solution:**

```
import scipy.stats
variables = [10, -2, 7]
maximum = max(variables)
probabilities = scipy.stats.norm(maximum, 1).pdf([variables])
```

**Result:**
    array([[  3.98942280e-01,   2.14638374e-32,   4.43184841e-03]])

The rest, you can figure out yourself.

(*) The reason for setting the `mean`to the largest value is to get the largest probability (weight) for it.

Comment: I guess the "arbitrary" (lol. 1? really?) standard deviation has a *big* effect on the resulting probabilities, so you probably:) have to play with it till you're satisfied with the results. `e-32` definitely doesn't sound right.

Answer (score -2):

Just my thought, what if you sum weights. And you get 19 + 4 (B positive is 2, diffrence is 4) + 7 = 30.

```
chanceA = 19 / 30 = 63%
chanceB = 2 / 30 = 6%
chanceC = 7 / 30 = 23%
```

You don't get 100% if you sum procentages but, it would maybe work :)

Comment: If b were 3 and c were -7 this would result in C having a larger  weight, which is wrong

Comment: Ups, you are correct.

Answer (score -4):

You can transform negative numbers to numbers. To numbers in [0;1] segment. like that

```
def chance(a):
   if a>0: 
       return a
   else: 
       return 1/abs(a)
```

also you should return something on 0

Comment: -1 would then be treated as 100%. Also -2 and +0.5 would end up with the same chance