# How to pick an item by its probability?

Tags: java, list, random, probability

I have a list of items. Each of these items has its own probability.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm to pick an item based on its probability?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

So with each item store a number that marks its relative probability, for example if you have 3 items one should be twice as likely to be selected as either of the other two then your list will have:

```
 [{A,1},{B,1},{C,2}]
```

Then sum the numbers of the list (i.e. 4 in our case).
Now generate a random number and choose that index.
int index = rand.nextInt(4);
return the number such that the index is in the correct range.

Java code:

```
class Item {
    int relativeProb;
    String name;

    //Getters Setters and Constructor
}

...

class RandomSelector {
    List<Item> items = new List();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int totalSum = 0;

    RandomSelector() {
        for(Item item : items) {
            totalSum = totalSum + item.relativeProb;
        }
    }

    public Item getRandom() {

        int index = rand.nextInt(totalSum);
        int sum = 0;
        int i=0;
        while(sum < index ) {
             sum = sum + items.get(i++).relativeProb;
        }
        return items.get(Math.max(0,i-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Usman. but I wonder should I take i-th item or (i-1)th item ? I mean items.get(i-1) instead of items.get(i)

Comment: Here `p` is any random number so how can we say that most probability item get selected first ..

eg:`[{A,10},{B,20}]` so how can you we say that suppose in first iteration `p=2` so `2<=10` is true and first item `{A,10}` is getting selected first even though second item have more probabilty

Comment: p is a random number from 0 to "Sum of all weights" so in your example there is a 10/30 = 1/3 chance of p being an number from 0-9 and there is a 20/30 = 2/3 change of p being a number from 10-29. Hence the chance of getting B is still twice as likely as getting A

Comment: Hey great answer but you have to be carefull! The function nextInt(...) returns a value from 0 (inclusive) to totalSum (exclusive). (See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)). So if 0 is picked (index = 0), you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, because you try to access items.get(-1), since you skip the while loop entirely and i = 0. Therefore you should return items.get(Math.max(0, i-1)).

Comment: Based on some experimentation this only worked for me if I replaced `int index = rand.nextInt(totalSum)` with `int index = rand.nextInt(totalSum) + 1` and then of course took out the redundant `Math.max`. Without this +1 I was getting twice as many of the "base" (and first) element in the list than expected, i.e. the first element in my list has a relative likelihood 1 by default, and everything else is with respect to that.

Answer (score 94):

1. Generate a uniformly distributed random number.
2. Iterate through your list until the cumulative probability of the visited elements is greater than the random number

Sample code:

```
double p = Math.random();
double cumulativeProbability = 0.0;
for (Item item : items) {
    cumulativeProbability += item.probability();
    if (p <= cumulativeProbability) {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here `p` is any random number so how can we say that most probability item get selected first ..

eg:`[{A,10},{B,20}]` so how can you we say that suppose in first iteration `p=2` so `2<=10` is true and first item `{A,10}` is getting selected first even though second item have more probabilty

Comment: @U2Answer, This algorithm requires the probabilities to be normalized (divided by the sum of all probabilities). By doing that you ensure that Σp_i=1 and then a random number between 0 and 1 will do the trick.

Comment: The order of the items in the list doesn't matter, because the value of `r` is a uniformly distributed random number, which means that the probability `r` be a certain value is equal to all other values `r` may be. Thus the items in the list are not "favored" and it doesn't matter where they are in the list.

Answer (score 33):

pretend that we have the following list

```
Item A 25%
Item B 15%
Item C 35%
Item D 5%
Item E 20%
```

Lets pretend that all the probabilities are integers, and assign each item a "range" that calculated as follows.

```
Start - Sum of probability of all items before
End - Start + own probability
```

The new numbers are as follows

```
Item A 0 to 25
Item B 26 to 40
Item C 41 to 75
Item D 76 to 80
Item E 81 to 100
```

Now pick a random number from 0 to 100. Lets say that you pick 32. 32 falls in Item B's range.

mj

Comment: This faster than @Brent's answer for selection, but it would take up way too much memory if say, the ranges were from 0 to a million.

Comment: Probabilities doesn't have to be percentages. We can just pick a random number between 0 to sum of the numbers.

Comment: should Item A be 1 to 25 instead of 0 to 25?

Comment: I believe it should be 1 to 25 as well, 0 to 25 would mean that Item A has a 26% probability.

Answer (score 16):

You can try the [Roulette Wheel Selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection).

First, add all the probabilities, then scale all the probabilities in the scale of 1, by dividing each one by the sum. Suppose the scaled probabilities are `A(0.4), B(0.3), C(0.25) and D(0.05)`. Then you can generate a random floating-point number in the range `[0, 1)`. Now you can decide like this:

```
random number in [0.00, 0.40) -> pick A
              in [0.40, 0.70) -> pick B
              in [0.70, 0.95) -> pick C
              in [0.95, 1.00) -> pick D
```

You can also do it with random integers - say you generate a random integer between 0 to 99 (inclusive), then you can make decision like the above.

Comment: (+1) It bothers me that this algorithm almost always seems to be described in terms of GAs (your link on Wikipedia and see [here](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~banerjee/selection.htm) also).  The weighted roulette wheel algorithm has all kinds of uses that have nothing to do with GAs (such as this very question).

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I also learned it's name while studying GAs, but I used the technique much before that for some other reason.

Comment: What will you pick if the random number is exact 0.40?

Comment: @Huy To resolve cases like this, the interval should be closed to the left and open to the right, i.e. `if 0.00 <= p < 0.40: pick A, else if 0.40 <= p < 0.70: pick B, ...`.

Answer (score 13):

Algorithm described in [Ushman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330493/3798217), [Brent's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330667/3798217) and @kaushaya's answers are implemented in [Apache commons-math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/index.html) library.

Take a look at [EnumeratedDistribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/EnumeratedDistribution.html) class (groovy code follows):

```
def probabilities = [
   new Pair<String, Double>("one", 25),
   new Pair<String, Double>("two", 30),
   new Pair<String, Double>("three", 45)]
def distribution = new EnumeratedDistribution<String>(probabilities)
println distribution.sample() // here you get one of your values
```

Note that sum of probabilities doesn't need to be equal to 1 or 100 - it will be normalized automatically.

Comment: Who is @kaushaya? May be s/he has changed name. So it is better to hyperlink the respective answers.

Answer (score 5):

My method is pretty simple. Generate a random number. Now since the probabilities of your items are known,simply iterate through the sorted list of probability and pick the item whose probability is lesser than the randomly generated number.

For more details,read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24014908/2477978).

Answer (score 5):

A slow but simple way to do it is to have every member to pick a random number based on its probability and pick the one with highest value.

**Analogy:**

Imagine 1 of 3 people needs to be chosen but they have different probabilities. You give them die with different amount of faces. First person's dice has 4 face, 2nd person's 6, and the third person's 8. They roll their die and the one with the biggest number wins.

Lets say we have the following list:

`[{A,50},{B,100},{C,200}]`

**Pseudocode:**

```
 A.value = random(0 to 50);
 B.value = random(0 to 100);
 C.value = random (0 to 200);
```

We pick the one with the highest value.

This method above does not exactly map the probabilities. For example 100 will not have twice the chance of 50. But we can do it in a by tweaking the method a bit.

**Method 2**

Instead of picking a number from 0 to the weight we can limit them from the upper limit of previous variable to addition of the current variable.

`[{A,50},{B,100},{C,200}]`

**Pseudocode:**

```
 A.lowLimit= 0; A.topLimit=50;
 B.lowLimit= A.topLimit+1; B.topLimit= B.lowLimit+100
 C.lowLimit= B.topLimit+1; C.topLimit= C.lowLimit+200
```

**resulting limits**

```
A.limits = 0,50
B.limits = 51,151
C.limits = 152,352
```

Then we pick a random number from 0 to 352 and compare it to each variable's limits to see whether the random number is in its limits.

I believe this tweak has better performance since there is only 1 random generation.

There is a similar method in other answers but this method does not require the total to be 100 or 1.00.

Comment: Why is this down voted? I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Your method does not map to probabilities as easily as it first seems. Suppose we want two choices, A and B. A has 2/5 = 0 to 40, B has 3/5 = 0 to 60. If we simulate this with your method, 1/3 of the time B will select between 41 and 60, guaranteeing success. Then the other 2/3 of the time, B will be 0 to 40 and A will be 0 to 40, giving them even odds, so that 1/2 of 2/3 of the time, B will win. That's 1/3 + 1/3 = 2/3, which is different from the expected 3/5 that B wins.

Comment: @MauveRanger It was never intended to exactly replicate the possibilities but the math seems to be misleading. I will edit and add another method of doing it that will hopefully be correct with the math.

Answer (score 5):

A space-costly way is to clone each item the number of times its probability. Selection will be done in O(1).

For example

```
//input
[{A,1},{B,1},{C,3}]

// transform into
[{A,1},{B,1},{C,1},{C,1},{C,1}]
```

Then simply pick any item randomly from this transformed list.

Comment: This should have a higher placement than it does, since it's important to be aware of the existince of an O(1) solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Brent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330667/3798217) is good, but it doesn't account for the possibility of erroneously choosing an item with a probability of 0 in cases where p = 0. That's easy enough to handle by checking the probability (or perhaps not adding the item in the first place):

```
double p = Math.random();
double cumulativeProbability = 0.0;
for (Item item : items) {
    cumulativeProbability += item.probability();
    if (p <= cumulativeProbability && item.probability() != 0) {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about the case where the item probability is zero. You should either have already exited the loop or you would continue over as the cumulative probability wouldn't have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228927/11257746 into a general extention method. This will allow you to get a weighted random value from a Dictionary with the structure <TKey, int>, where int is a weight value.

A Key that has a value of 50 is 10 times more likely to be chosen than a key with the value of 5.

**C# code using LINQ:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a random key out of a dictionary which has integer values treated as weights. 
/// A key in the dictionary with a weight of 50 is 10 times more likely to be chosen than an element with the weight of 5.
/// 
/// Example usage to get 1 item: 
/// Dictionary<MyType, int> myTypes;
/// MyType chosenType = myTypes.GetWeightedRandomKey<MyType, int>().First();
/// 
/// Adapted into a general extention method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37228927/11257746
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TKey> GetWeightedRandomKey<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, int> dictionaryWithWeights)
{
    int totalWeights = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, int> pair in dictionaryWithWeights)
    { 
        totalWeights += pair.Value;
    }

    System.Random random = new System.Random();
    while (true)
    {
        int randomWeight = random.Next(0, totalWeights);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, int> pair in dictionaryWithWeights)
        {
            int weight = pair.Value;

            if (randomWeight - weight > 0)
                randomWeight -= weight;
            else
            {
                yield return pair.Key;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
public enum MyType { Thing1, Thing2, Thing3 }
public Dictionary<MyType, int> MyWeightedDictionary = new Dictionary<MyType, int>();

public void MyVoid()
{
    MyWeightedDictionary.Add(MyType.Thing1, 50);
    MyWeightedDictionary.Add(MyType.Thing2, 25);
    MyWeightedDictionary.Add(MyType.Thing3, 5);
    
    // Get a single random key
    MyType myChosenType = MyWeightedDictionary.GetWeightedRandomKey<MyType, int>().First();
    
    // Get 20 random keys
    List<MyType> myChosenTypes = MyWeightedDictionary.GetWeightedRandomKey<MyType, int>().Take(20).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a third party dependency in your code you can use the [MockNeat.probabilities()](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat/wiki/MockNeat#probabilities) method.

For example:

```
String s = mockNeat.probabilites(String.class)
                .add(0.1, "A") // 10% chance to pick A
                .add(0.2, "B") // 20% chance to pick B
                .add(0.5, "C") // 50% chance to pick C
                .add(0.2, "D") // 20% chance to pick D
                .val();
```

*Disclaimer: I am the author of the library, so I might be biased when I am recommending it.*

Answer (score 0):

All mentioned solutions have linear effort. The following has only logarithmic effort and deals also with unnormalized probabilities. I'd reccommend to use a TreeMap rather than a List:

```java
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

    public class ProbabilityMap<T> extends TreeMap<Double,T>{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static Random random = new Random();
        public double sumOfProbabilities;
        public Map.Entry<Double,T> next() {
            return ceilingEntry(random.nextDouble()*sumOfProbabilities);
        }
        @Override public T put(Double key, T value) {
            return super.put(sumOfProbabilities+=key, value);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ProbabilityMap<Integer> map = new ProbabilityMap<>();
            map.put(0.1,1);  map.put(0.3,3);    map.put(0.2,2);
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i->System.out.println(map.next()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a horrible case of inheritance for implementation, but a totally valid point. 

If you're going to do a lot of look ups and have a lot of entries then TreeMap looks like a fun approach. 

(You'd probably have to profile it to decide if it actually offered any runtime benefit - I'm not arguing the O log(n) vs O(n) win here but there's a mental overhead in figuring out how TreeMap works and it might not be worth it.)

I like it and hate it simultaneously :)

Comment: Yes, TreeMap has drawbacks e.g. for iteration and construction. However, if you have a lot of entries, picking should be clearly faster than linear approaches.

Comment: I roughly tested the performance of TreeMap picking. It's about 5 times faster as the accepted solution if I pick in the middle of the items. For 100 items TreeMap is 5 times faster, for 10000 items TreeMap is 17 times faster.

Answer (score -3):

You could use the Julia code:

```
function selrnd(a::Vector{Int})
    c = a[:]
    sumc = c[1]
    for i=2:length(c)
        sumc += c[i]
        c[i] += c[i-1]
    end
    r = rand()*sumc
    for i=1:length(c)
        if r <= c[i]
            return i
        end
    end
end
```

This function returns the index of an item efficiently.