# Pick random element from list with probability

Tags: c#, list, random, probability

I Have a list that contains four item (A, B, C, D). Every item has a probability to be chosen. Let's say for example A has 74% of chance to be picked, B 15%, C 7% ,and D 4%.

I want to create a function that choose randomly an item according to its probability.

Any help please?

Comment: You must give it a try first, and we'll help you with any problems you encounter. SO doesn't write code entirely for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330394/how-to-pick-an-item-by-its-probability

Comment: Generate random number from 0 to 1. If it is less than A probability (<0.74) - choose A. Otherwise if it is less than A+B probability (< 0.74+0.15) - choose B, and so on.

Comment: @Evk: Suppose there are a large number n of buckets.  Can you come up with an algorithm that does not involve making O(n) comparisons?

Comment: @EricLippert I myself can only come up with binary search in that list of cumulated probabilities (List.BinarySearch will do), but I found this algorithm: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method which (after nlog(n) one-time preparation) can do this in o(1) time.

Comment: What's wrong in choosing something as `random(s.length())` as index for string `s` `"AAAAB"` (or array) where `A` is 80% and `B` is 20% (apart from the assumption that the probability needs to be whole numbers)? So O(1) space and O(1) time.

Comment: @hlppy that works but it is not o(1) in time or space if the distribution is unknown at compile time. Its at least linear in both to build the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define a class for your items like this:

```
class Items<T>
{
    public double Probability { get; set; }
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

then initialize it

```
var initial = new List<Items<string>>
{
    new Items<string> {Probability = 74 / 100.0, Item = "A"},
    new Items<string> {Probability = 15 / 100.0, Item = "B"},
    new Items<string> {Probability = 7 / 100.0, Item = "C"},
    new Items<string> {Probability = 4 / 100.0, Item = "D"},
};
```

then you need to convert it to aggregate a sum of probabilities from 0 to 1

```
var converted = new List<Items<string>>(initial.Count);
var sum = 0.0;
foreach (var item in initial.Take(initial.Count - 1))
{
    sum += item.Probability;
    converted.Add(new Items<string> {Probability = sum, Item = item.Item});
}
converted.Add(new Items<string> {Probability = 1.0, Item = initial.Last().Item});
```

now you can pick an item from `converted` collection with respect to probability:

```
var rnd = new Random();
while (true)
{
    var probability = rnd.NextDouble();
    var selected = converted.SkipWhile(i => i.Probability < probability).First();
    Console.WriteLine($"Selected item = {selected.Item}");
}
```

NOTE: my implementation have `O(n)` complexity. You can optimize it with binary search (because values in `converted` collection are sorted)

Answer (score 2):

My apologies for answering this one like this - I'm kinda viewing it as a sort of "Euler.Net" puzzle, and a way of playing around with Generics.

Anyway, here's my go at it:

```
public class WeightedItem<T>
{
    private T value;
    private int weight;
    private int cumulativeSum;
    private static Random rndInst = new Random();

    public WeightedItem(T value, int weight)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public static T Choose(List<WeightedItem<T>> items)
    {
        int cumulSum = 0;
        int cnt = items.Count();

        for (int slot = 0; slot < cnt; slot++)
        {
            cumulSum += items[slot].weight;
            items[slot].cumulativeSum = cumulSum;
        }

        double divSpot = rndInst.NextDouble() * cumulSum;
        WeightedItem<T> chosen =  items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.cumulativeSum >= divSpot);
        if (chosen == null) throw new Exception("No item chosen - there seems to be a problem with the probability distribution.");
        return chosen.value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        WeightedItem<string> alice = new WeightedItem<string>("alice", 1);
        WeightedItem<string> bob = new WeightedItem<string>("bob", 1);
        WeightedItem<string> charlie = new WeightedItem<string>("charlie", 1);
        WeightedItem<string> diana = new WeightedItem<string>("diana", 4);
        WeightedItem<string> elaine = new WeightedItem<string>("elaine", 1);

        List<WeightedItem<string>> myList = new List<WeightedItem<string>> { alice, bob, charlie, diana, elaine };
        string chosen = WeightedItem<string>.Choose(myList);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;

public class Test{
    private static String[] values = {"A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D",};

    private static Random PRNG = new Random();

    public static void Main(){
        Console.WriteLine( values[PRNG.Next(values.Length)] );
    }
}
```