# How to select and element according to its probability in c#?

Tags: c#

For two given arrays the first for items ( elements) and the second for their probabilities how to select a number based the probability ? in c#

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: Can you add sample code and show us an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pick random element from list with probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735106/pick-random-element-from-list-with-probability)

Comment: How does the arrays look like? and when you say "select a number based the probability" what does that mean? A method where you supply the probability, and you want the corresponding number? or you want to sort the list by probability and take the one with the highest?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const int SIZE = 4;//write your size

    var array = new int[SIZE] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };//fill your items
    var probabilities = new double[SIZE] { 43.5, 20, 100, 13.5 };//fill your probabilities

    for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.Length; i++)
    {
        int countOfTempItem = array.Count(x => x == array[i]);
        var probOfArrayTempItem = (double)((countOfTempItem / array.Length) * 100);
        if (probabilities[i] == probOfArrayTempItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Item: {array[i]} - Probability {probabilities[i]}");
        }
    }
```

May be this can help you.