# Choose X Elements from a List With Probabilties

Tags: random, dart, flutter

I have to make a List of let's say 10 items of different types.

For example:

- item A. probability 90%
- item B. probability 90%
- item C. probability 90%
- item D. probability 30%
- item E. probability 20%
- item F. probability 10%
- item G. probability 1%

How could I get this list?

I've tried an approach showed by the first and for the third down (based on upvote) answers under this question: [How to pick an item by its probability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330394/how-to-pick-an-item-by-its-probability/9330667)
But as far as I understood all of these need a code line for every possible element, for example,  `if(Random.nextDouble(1) <= item.probability){List.add(item)}` and while mathematically correct, this approach would request new logic for every item and wouldn't be easy to adjust to new items and wouldn't fit well with items that have the same probability of appearing.

I cannot quite understand The Second Question (The Accepted One), but as far as I've understood it also uses a per-item way of doing it (I Might be wrong, sorry, it's very condensed and it's java).

So I was looking for something more like this: 
[A weighted version of random.choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice)
The answer I linked is in python, and is a single line implementation of the method numpy.choice which could then be put into a cicle from 0 to X to run X times. Is there a way of doing something like this in Dart?

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: Nope, It's for a "game" I'm writing :)  I don't have computer technology at School

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330394/how-to-pick-an-item-by-its-probability/9330667, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679694/a-weighted-version-of-random-choice

Comment: I've asked because I couldn't find anything for dart, the answer you pointed is for java, I'll try to see if I could use it in dart too

Comment: What part of the Java code causes you troubles to translate to Dart?

Comment: I tried converting the first answer but I think this isn't what I'm looking forward to. I might have made an error asking the question. I'll edit it, sorry

Comment: Then please post the code you got and how it does not do what you expect. SO is not free code-monkey service. You should show some own effort.

Comment: I've edited the question.